# Cooking with Hemp Protein Powder

Tags: baking, temperature

I was considering making baking goods with protein powder and was considering Hemp Protein Powder.  I see most of the recipes often use Hemp Hearts but didn't find much with the protein powder form.  Is that Hemp Protein Powder a form that can normally be baked with, and is there a recommended cooking temperature limit?

Will any protein powder work for cooking or should I be selective?

Comment: Much of plant protein is in the form of a single enzyme, RuBisCO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuBisCO#Depletion_in_proteomic_studies , trouble is, what determines taste will likely be trace non-protein components of the flour; Chlorophylls and such. Only way to find out if a particular plant protein mix will work for you is to taste some and see.